# Linked List Optimization

Tags: java, optimization, linked-list

I'm working on this program that emulates restriction enzymes and DNA splicing. I'm using DnaSequenceNode[s] as linked list nodes.

I have a problem with one of the function in my code, cutSplice() is supposed to create a new DnaStrand that is a clone of the current DnaStrand, but with every instance of enzyme replaced by splicee.

For example, if the LinkedDnaStrand is instantiated with "TTGATCC", and
cutSplice("GAT", "TTAAGG") is called, then the linked list should become something like (previous pointers not shown):

first -> "TT" -> "TTAAGG" -> "CC" -> null

My function works. However, my method cutSplice() takes more than 80 seconds to splice 200 DNAs. I'm supposed to bring that 80 seconds to 2 seconds.

This is all my code for the class : [LinkedDnaStrand.java](http://pastebin.com/niPSTUa2)

And here's the code for the method cutSplice()

```
public DnaStrand cutSplice(String enzyme, String splicee) {
    DnaStrand newStrand = null;
    String original_Dna = this.toString();
    String new_Dna = original_Dna.replaceAll(enzyme, splicee);
    String[] splicee_split = new_Dna.split(splicee); // splits the new DNA string DnaStrand
    newStrand = null;
    int i = 0;
    if (original_Dna.startsWith(enzyme)) {
        newStrand = new LinkedDnaStrand(splicee);
    } else {
        newStrand = new LinkedDnaStrand(splicee_split[0]);
        newStrand.append(splicee);
    }
    for (i = 1; i < splicee_split.length - 1; i++) {

        String node = splicee_split[i];
        newStrand.append(node);
        newStrand.append(splicee);

    }
    newStrand.append(splicee_split[splicee_split.length - 1]);

    if (original_Dna.endsWith(enzyme)) {
        newStrand.append(splicee);
    }


    return newStrand;
}
```

Does anybody see anything that could make a critical difference on the time this function takes to process 200 DNAs sample?

Comment: Maybe you should provide a working test. Something we can run with whatever data input you are using that is causing this 80 second runtime.

Comment: First of all: Why are you implement a linked list on your own and then working with Strings. That doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: Easiest way to solve your problem: Fire up [VisualVM](https://visualvm.java.net/) (it's included in Oracle's JDK), learn to use it and profile your code. You'll find out the hotspots and if you need help working those out, create a new question. You'll also learn to profile your application, which is something all programmers need to know. One thing I noticed is that you're using `split()` and `replaceAll()`, both of which use regular expressions, which you probably don't need, and which require additional processing power.

Comment: You can use `replace()` instead of `replaceAll()` to use the non-regexp version. For `split()` you're going to have to use `StringTokenizer` or `Scanner` (and write some additional code).

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is comfortable to use the string methods, but you are losing time in converting to the string, back to sequence, and (as pointed out in the previous comments) with the regex based string functions.

It will certainly consume less time to operate on the linked list directly, although this will require you to implement the replacement algorithm yourself:

```java
@Override
public LinkedDnaStrand cutSplice(String enzyme, String splicee)
{
    LinkedDnaStrand strand = new LinkedDnaStrand();
    DnaSequenceNode end = null;
    DnaSequenceNode begin = top;
    int pos = 0;
    DnaSequenceNode tmpStart, tmpEnd;
    for (DnaSequenceNode current = top; current != null; current = current.next)
    {
        if(current.value != enzyme.charAt(pos))
        {
            tmpStart = tmpEnd = new DnaSequenceNode(begin.value);
            for (DnaSequenceNode n = begin.next; n != current.next; n = n.next)
            {
                DnaSequenceNode c = new DnaSequenceNode(n.value);
                tmpEnd.next = c;
                c.previous = tmpEnd;
                tmpEnd = c;
            }
        }
        else if(++pos == enzyme.length())
        {
            tmpStart = tmpEnd = new DnaSequenceNode(splicee.charAt(0));
            for (int i = 1; i < splicee.length(); ++i)
            {
                DnaSequenceNode c = new DnaSequenceNode(splicee.charAt(i));
                tmpEnd.next = c;
                c.previous = tmpEnd;
                tmpEnd = c;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            continue;
        }

        if(end == null)
        {
            strand.top = end = tmpStart;
        }
        else
        {
            end.next = tmpStart;
            tmpStart.previous = end;
        }
        end = tmpEnd;
        begin = current.next;
        pos = 0;
    }

    return strand;
}
```

I do not claim that there is not any opportunity to further optimize, but this should be a lot faster as the original version. I tested it successfully with the example you gave, if you yet find a bug, feel free to fix it yourself...

Note 1: I did explicitely create a new sequence from the string (instead of using the constructor) to get the end of the sequence without having to iterate over it again.

Note 2: I assumed existing a constructor `DnaSequenceNode(char value)` and DnaSequenceNode having a member `public char value`. You might have to adjust the code appropriately if any of these assumptions fails.